# Spring threshold file size

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, multipart, filesize

In version 2.1.3, Failed to bind properties under 'spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold' to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize

Property:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
```

Exception:

> Description:
>
> Failed to bind properties under
> 'spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold' to
> org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize:
>
> ```
> Property: spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold
> Value: 2KB 
> Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:24:46
> Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Update your application's configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing space in the property's value. You have configured a size of `2KB`  and it should be `2KB`.